# Coq Real numbers -lexing and parsing 3.14

Tags: coq, real-number

With Reals library imported

```
Require Import Reals.
```

How can I define constants such as 3.14 or 10.1 and use them for function definition or computation ?

Comment: Does `Definition threefourteen : R := 314/100.` not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your constants like so:

```
Definition a := 10 + /10.
Definition b := 3 + 14/100.
```

Note, however, that the standard library defines reals *axiomatically*.
You can find the main definitions [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Rdefinitions.html). Observe that the definitions are given as `Parameter`s, which is a synonym for `Axiom`.
For instance, `R0` and `R1` stand for the real numbers 0 and 1, `Rplus` and `Rmult` represent addition and multiplication, but those definitions are not inductive datatypes and functions as they lack definitions. To be able to deal with reals we need axioms, governing the interactions between them (given [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Reals.Raxioms.html)).

You can think of the real numbers in the standard library as [ASTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), made with nodes marked `R0`, `R1`, `Rplus`, and so on. And you are given some rules (axioms) which specify the (only) transformations you can perform on those ASTs.

Let's see how Coq represents real numbers:

```
Require Import Coq.Reals.Reals.
Local Open Scope R_scope.
Unset Printing Notations.
Check 5+/2  (* 5½ *).

(*
Rplus (Rplus R1
             (Rmult (Rplus R1 R1)
                    (Rplus R1 R1)))
      (Rinv (Rplus R1 R1)).
i.e. (1 + (1 + 1) * (1 + 1)) + (1 + 1)⁻¹ 
*)
```

Among the consequences of this axiomatic approach there is the fact that the following goal cannot be proved by `reflexivity` anymore (as it could be done for `nat`s in an analogous situation):

```
Set Printing Notations.
Goal a = 9 + 1 + /10.
  Fail reflexivity.
```

This fails because the ASTs (terms) on the both sides of the equality are different and Coq doesn't convert them to some canonical values to compare them at the end. This time we need to show that the two ASTs are mutually convertible.

```
  enough (9 + 1 = 10).
  - now rewrite H.
```

Now we need to prove `9 + 1 = 10`:

```
  - rewrite Rplus_comm, <-Rplus_assoc.
    rewrite <-(Rmult_1_r 2) at 1.
    rewrite <-Rmult_plus_distr_l.
    reflexivity.
```

Fortunately for us there is a tactic, which can do this tedious job for us:

```
    Restart.
    unfold a; field.
Qed.
```

The standard library approach is not the only one possible, however.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28543790/2747511) by @gallais can help you with exploring your other options.

Comment: Very useful examples & links in your answer. Thanks Anton.